# Error: Getting error on adding value in list of collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have created list of `List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>>` and i am trying add value in that list. PFB code for that.

```
public string Get(Hello request)
{
  string html= "[{'Id':1},{'Id':2}]"; 
  List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>> lsData = null;
  var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(html); //parse json Array  

 for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++) // loop one element on json array and parse it.
 {
   var obj = values[i];
   Dictionary<string, string> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(obj.ToString());
   lsData.Add(i, data); //Showing error here
 }
 return "success";
}
```

but this code showing error below .`The type arguments for method 'ServiceStack.ServiceRoute Extensions.Add<T>(ServiceStack.Web.IService Routes, strong, ServiceStack.ApplyTo, params System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T,object>>[])' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

I dont understand why it is showing error. thanks in advance.

Comment: Uhm are you sure that should work at all? From what I see you deserialize the json which is ok. But THEN you deserialize it again? (aka deserializing something deserialized)

Comment: Does this compiles, lsData.Add(i, data), you need a Dictionary object for the List, it cannot be Key value directly, no overload of List will provide this functionality, until and unless its an extension created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is in this line `lsData.Add(i, data);`, since you are trying to add a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>` to a given list, now it require two things:

1. Initialized `Dictionary<string,string>`, which you are doing as you are doing in the following line:

   ```
   Dictionary<string, string> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(obj.ToString());
   ```

Assuming the `Deserialization` works correctly, but when you make the call for list addition, its erroneous since its like adding value to a `Dictionary`, not to a `List`, therefore make following changes:

Add the following code in the for loop:

```
var lsDataDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>();
lsDataDictionary.Add(i.ToString(),data)
lsData.Add(lsDataDictionary);
```

Please note for `lsDataDictionary` key is string, to the `for loop counter` needs to be converted to `string`

Comment: For clarification: As for the deserialization so the error is caused not because he deserializes the same structure 2 times, but because he tries to deserialize into a dictionary instead of a list?

Comment: Why is deserializing in a Dictionary a problem, that will work out of box, it he has dictionary inside the object, it cannot be deserialized to a list

Comment: I wasn't too sure from the description what you meant but just got it that you meant the adding itself not the deserialization he did.

Comment: Yes, I am under the assumption that Deserialization is working correctly, there's no way for me to verify that, but even if it fails and yield a null object the list addition is anyway erroneous

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate the lsData

```
lsData = new List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>>();
```

Comment: Oh just saw it, sorry.
Anyway you must instantiate it and I cannot see it in the code you posted

Comment: Try: Dictionary<string, string> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(obj.ToString()) as Dictionary<string, string>;